# Can I copy a Linux virtual LAMP setup to a real server?

Tags: linux, apache, virtual-machine, vagrant, lamp

I'm setting up a full development environment with a virtual machine (LAMP). After testing locally I will then set up a publicly accessible web server and launch the site.

I'm going to use Vagrant to deal with the virtual machine setup on my Mac.

When this is all completed, I obviously upload/commit the website files to a public web server, but do I (or can I) also have the virtual machine setup uploaded to the public (and real) web server?

I think not, but it would make sense to me to configure the Linux (I'll use Ubuntu) virtual machine locally (security, etc.) with Vagrant/SHH etc. and then use that same config when going live.

So basically there's two options:

```
(1) No, use Vagrant to set up LAMP, but the same setup then needs to be manually configured on a real server
(2) Yes, you can have your LAMP config used on a real server (and how do I do this)
```

Comment: Are you wanting to use virtualization on the production server?

Comment: Hi, thanks. No, the production server to be a fully live / real server. I'm using a Rackspace Cloud Server, but it seems like configs for Apache / PHP etc. need to be done both on the Rackspace Cloud Server and also in my local virtual machine. It makes sense to me to just configure the local machine and 'upload' this config to the Rackspace Cloud Server. Is that possible?

Comment: So if you are using a cloud-based (virtualized) approach to deploying your service, why would you not use a cloud-based approach to developing it?  Why not have a separate server instance your use for development. When ready to go to production, you can snapshot the machine image and deploy that image to production.

Comment: To be honest, in the many years I have been developing on the web I have never created a virtual machine, and have always hosted a http://testsite.mysite.com URL - which I have always preferred. People tell me this is slow (uploading to test on the web etc.), and suggest a virtual machine. I think you are telling me I was right all along. I think your suggestion is 100% exactly how I already do it.

Comment: Well maybe yes and no.  Unless you have the ability to snapshot your virtual machine image on your local machine and deploy that to your Rackspace account, then you really don't have virtualization that is compatible such that you can seemlessly move machine images back and forth between Dev and Prod environements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is use something to help with configuration automation.  Puppet and Chef are some popular ones, and you could always "roll your own", but I know puppet can help you easily replicate your configuration on both your VM and your production server.

Checkout http://www.puppetlabs.com

There's also Puppet Forge which has a lot of available modules that are already built for helping configuring things like Apache, and other server technologies you might be using.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox, VMWare are only [providers](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/providers/index.html), you can find plugin for use [DigitalOcean](https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-digitalocean) or AWS (or you can [create your provider](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/plugins/providers.html)) how providers and you can install your service in production ENV.

This is a (blog article)[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-digitalocean-as-your-provider-in-vagrant-on-an-ubuntu-12-10] for DigitalOcean.. In this example use shell how provisioning system

Answer (score 0):

A very flexible way to achieve this, being also cloud provider independent, is to define your LAMP server using [ElasticBox](http://elasticbox.com).

There is a tutorial that shows you what are the steps to achieve the one click automated deployment of your customized LAMP environment:

https://elasticbox.com/documentation/sample-tutorials/lamp-stack/